# Repeating slideshow (CssSlidy)

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using [this very simple library](https://github.com/dudleystorey/CSSslidy) to create a slideshow of pictures. Problem is that when the slideshow gets to the last picture, it doesn't repeat.

The function to start the slideshow is cssSlidy(). [Here](https://github.com/dudleystorey/CSSslidy/blob/gh-pages/cssslidy.js) it is. I know I need to manipulate the function in some way but not sure how I would go about it.

Comment: Post some of your code - it looks to me like CSSslidy repeats by default ([demo](http://demosthenes.info/blog/838/CSSslidy-An-Auto-Generated-Responsive-CSS3-Image-Slider)), so it could be the rest of your code that is preventing it from repeating.

Comment: Hah - interesting. Thanks for finding this. I think it'll be a lot easier for you if I describe what I'm doing on the site rather than posting all of my code. The biggest difference between the demo slideshow you found and my slideshow is that I am making an api request and then creating a bunch of img tags on the fly within the <figure> tag. Each img tag has a different remote src  .  The rest of the changes are minor (adjusting image sizes through css, adding a picture within the caption, changing the background color etc).

Comment: Perhaps try calling the CSSslidy code after your API requests finish and you have your `<figure>` tag fully formed.

Comment: yep this is exactly what i'm doing.  I'm looking over the code from the demo to see if there's any difference when compared to the cssSlidy() function that I am using but can't seem to find anything different.

Comment: Hi @MaximillianLaumeister, I wanted to let you know that I fixed my issue.  The slideshow was actually being repeated as you had pointed out but it would stop in a black screen for a long time for some reason. The problem was that in every frame in the slideshow I had 2 images, and the javascript was counting every image in the slideshow and measuring the total time assuming that each frame only had 1 image.  Dividing the image length by 2 did the trick

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!